# Clear/Remove attached handlers to $.Deferred Objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Very simple question, thought I could figure this one out but the answer has eluded me.

Is it possible to clear/remove attached handlers to a deferred object done/fail/always queues.

```
var dfd = $.Deferred()

dfd.done(foo).fail(bar);

// User interacts with the page in a way that I do not want to fire foo or bar 
// when dfd is resolved or rejected

<<answer here>>
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is no, but I won't swear it. You can accomplish at least part (if not all) of what you want without that functionality anyway.

You can always set things up to wait on multiple deferreds with `$.when`. So, instead of

```
var dfd= $.Deferred();
dfd.done(foo).fail(bar);
```

You'd have

```
var dfd= $.Deferred();
var userfailedtointeract= $.Deferred();
$.when(dfd,userfailedtointeract).done(foo);
```

Which you'd resolve `userfailedtointeract` after which point it's safe to call foo or reject otherwise

However, this does not take care of conditionally calling `bar`, as adding the `.fail(bar)` to the above `$.when` line means `bar` fires when either of the promises are rejected. You only want `bar` to fire on failure only if `userfailedtointeract` was resolved!

That leads us to the following:

```
var dfd= $.Deferred();
var userfailedtointeract= $.Deferred();
userfailedtointeract.done(function(){
    dfd.done(foo).fail(bar);
});
```

Which... actually isn't a hard a solution as I thought it would be. But I'm looking at this with insomniac eyes. I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no mechanism to remove already-registered callbacks on a `$.Deferred()`.

Most times, you only have access to the `.promise()` interface of the deferred, and this only allows you to register callbacks and read the promise's state - you cannot *modify* the promise through any exposed methods.

In your case, you will need those registered callbacks to check some other state variable that is altered by the user interaction, and then have them decide whether to continue or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may just be looking at the problem wrong. It seems like what you really want to do is cancel (abort) the XHR so that your deferred can be ignored.

This answer on a similar question shows an example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11863085/545296

Comment: I don't think this will prevent the deferred from being fired? What will actually happen is it will cause the deferred to be rejected and call 'fail'.